# CircleImageView error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException on Picasso.load() from firebase storage

Tags: java, android, xml

I am trying to get an image from the firebase storage and load it into a Circle Image View on the navigation header. I used picasso to set the file into the view but it retuns null...I can't find out why.

- minSdkVersion 19
- targetSdkVersion 28
- dependency for the view:  implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:3.0.0'

That's the error i get:

```
03-15 05:42:37.178 23532-23532/com.example.lnf E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.lnf, PID: 23532
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.lnf/com.example.lnf.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Target must not be null.
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2416)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
 Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Target must not be null.
    at com.squareup.picasso.RequestCreator.into(RequestCreator.java:682)
    at com.squareup.picasso.RequestCreator.into(RequestCreator.java:665)
    at com.example.lnf.MainActivity.LoadImgToCircleView(MainActivity.java:97)
    at com.example.lnf.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:85)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369)
```

Main Activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
    implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {
private FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth;
private DatabaseReference databaseReference;
private StorageReference profileImgRef;
private CircleImageView circleImageViewMain;
private TextView name, email;
String hearderImgUrl;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar =  findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    //Initialize Firebase modules
    firebaseAuth=FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    databaseReference= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("users");
    profileImgRef= FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference();



    circleImageViewMain =findViewById(R.id.circleImageHeader);
    name=findViewById(R.id.txtName);
    email=findViewById(R.id.txtEmail);

    FloatingActionButton fab =  findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("Action", null).show();
        }
    });

    DrawerLayout drawer =  findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
    drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.syncState();

    NavigationView navigationView =  findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

    LoadImgToCircleView(CheckUserDataBase());

}

private void LoadImgToCircleView(String uid) {
    try {
        File localFile =File.createTempFile("profile","png");
        StorageReference filepath=profileImgRef.child(uid).child("profileImg/profile.png");
        filepath.getFile(localFile);
        Picasso.get()
                .load(localFile)
                .placeholder(R.drawable.ic_account)
                .into(circleImageViewMain);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();

    FirebaseUser user=firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
    if (user == null){
        SendUserToLogin();
    } else {
        CheckUserDataBase();

    }

}

private String CheckUserDataBase() {
    final String userID =firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();
    databaseReference.addValueEventListener(
            new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    if (!dataSnapshot.child(userID).hasChild("userInfo")){
                        SendUserToSetup();
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

                }
            }
    );

    return userID;
}

private void SendUserToSetup() {
    Intent i = new Intent(this,SetupActivity.class);
    i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK|Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
    startActivity(i);
}

private void SendUserToLogin() {
    Intent i = new Intent(this,LoginActivity.class);
    i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK|Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
    startActivity(i);
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    DrawerLayout drawer =  findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

@SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    if (id == R.id.nav_home) {
        // Handle the camera action
    } else if (id == R.id.nav_profile) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_my_posts) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_messeges) {

    } else if (id == R.id.action_settings) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_logout) {
        firebaseAuth.signOut();
        SendUserToLogin();

    }

    DrawerLayout drawer =  findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    return true;
}
```

}

navigation_header_main.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="@dimen/nav_header_height"
android:background="@drawable/login"
android:gravity="bottom"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark">

<de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
    android:id="@+id/circleImageHeader"
    android:layout_width="120dp"
    android:layout_height="120dp"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/nav_header_vertical_spacing"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_account"
    app:civ_border_color="@color/colorAccent"
    app:civ_border_width="3dp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txtName"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/nav_header_vertical_spacing"
    android:text="@string/nav_header_title"
    android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body1" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txtEmail"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/nav_header_subtitle" />
```

build.gradle (app)

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'


android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.lnf"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        android.defaultConfig.vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true

    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.7'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.1.0'
    implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:3.0.0'
    api 'com.theartofdev.edmodo:android-image-cropper:2.6.+'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:16.1.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'
    implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-storage:4.1.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first log you image url is coming from firebase or not after that you have to do like that.

```
//Nav Header Section
//Here I am using glide you can use picasso
    View header = navigationView.getHeaderView(0);
    navImageView = header.findViewById(R.id.nav_ImageView);
    navTextView = header.findViewById(R.id.nav_Textview);
    navTextView.setText(sharedPreferences.getString("name", ""));
    Log.d("success121", String.valueOf(navTextView));
    navText = sharedPreferences.getString("logo",null);
    if(navText!=null) {
        Log.e("Photo Url: ", navText);
        RequestOptions requestOptions = new RequestOptions();
        requestOptions.placeholder(R.drawable.ic_launcher_background);
        requestOptions.error(R.drawable.ic_launcher_foreground);

        Glide.with(this).load(navText)
                .apply(requestOptions).thumbnail(0.5f).into(navImageView);

    }
```

and in your code you are not saying to compiler where it set your image .
according to your code, compiler try to set image on activity not navigation header.

Comment: thanks @BlackBlind, it worked...i just inicializated header and set the image view

Answer (score 0):

First Change your initialization in your activity file, like this

```
circleImageViewMain =(CircleImageView)findViewById(R.id.circleImageHeader);
name=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtName);
email=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtEmail);
FloatingActionButton fab =  (FloatingActionButton)findViewById(R.id.fab);
DrawerLayout drawer =  (DrawerLayout)findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
```

After tell me what error log, comming

then remove your load your image with picaso, replace with this

```
if(filepath.exists())
{
Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filepath.getAbsolutePath());
circleImageViewMain.setImageBitmap(myBitmap);
}
```

Comment: done! it keeps crashing with the same error

Comment: line 97 on the main activity; the method into() from Picasso

Comment: now check updated, code

Comment: cannot resolve methods "exists()" and "getAbsolutePath()"

Comment: what is your error log, now ?

Comment: I could not even compile it, becouse of the methods